# Expected initializer before < token - structures and templates

Tags: c++, c++11

I am getting this exact error while practicing listings from one of my programming books... I have literally no clue; mb I'm blind or sth. Please help.
I've tried various other combinations but this one below seems to be most visible for what I have to do. There is still no classes so I wonder if its somehow connected to the using namespace std.

EDIT#1 Forgot to add on which line: 11, 22

```
#include <iostream>
template <typename T>
void swap (T &a, T &b);

struct job{
    char name[40];
    double salary;
    int floor;
};

template <> void Swap<job>(job &j1, job &j2);
void Show(job &j);

int main(){
    using namespace std;
    cout.precision(2);
    cout.setf(ios::fixed, ios::floatfield);
    int i = 10, j = 20;
    cout << "i, j =" << i << ", " << j << ".\n";
    cout << "Using generated by compiler function "
            "changing int value:\n";
    Swap(i,j);
    cout << "Now i, j = " << i << ", " << j << ".\n";
    job sue = {"Susan Yaffee", 73000.60, 7};
    job sidney = {"Sidney Taffee", 78060.72, 9};
    cout << "Before changing job structure:\n";
    Show(sue);
    Show(sidney);
    Swap(sue, sidney);
    cout << "After changing job structure:\n";
    Show(sue);
    Show(sidney);
    cin.get();
    return 0;
}

template <typename T>
void Swap(T &a, T &b){
    using namespace std;
    T temp;
    temp = a;
    a = b;
    b = temp;
}

template <> void Swap<job>(job &j1, job &j2){
    using namespace std;
    double t1;
    int t2;
    t1 = j1.salary;
    j1.salary = j2.salary;
    j2.salary = t1;
    t2 = j1.floor;
    j1.floor = j2.floor;
    j2.floor = t2;
}

void Show(job &j){
    using namespace std;
    cout << j.name << ": " << j.salary << "$ at floor " << j.floor << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#include <iostream>
template <typename T>
void swap (T &a, T &b);
```

Pretty sure you meant `Swap` here.

Without it, the subsequent specialisation cannot be compiled.

The words `swap` and `Swap` are different because C++ is case-sensitive.

Take care when transcribing from your book.

Comment: OMG. thanks boss! Im just starting and haha... funny how one lower case letter can change the whole meaning

Comment: Easily done. With more experience you will learn how to recognise familiar error patterns and, consequently, how to very quickly spot the cause (and fix it!)